# How to Level Measure a fluid from under/inside/below the liquid? | Level Measurement Instruments

Tags: measurements, fluid-statics, liquid-state

**Level Measurement in liquids.** I'm aware of all direct & indirect methods of measurement in Level Measurement.
However, what are some methods that enable us to measure fluids from inside, or below whilst being inside the same container?

Responses would help a lot in formulating my assignment!

Answer (score 0):

a sound wave, aimed up at the surface of the water from below the surface, will bounce off the surface and return to you. the distance between you and the surface can be determined by knowing the velocity of sound in water and the round-trip time of the sound wave.